# How to change fields permission using some action in the Rules module?

Tags: entities, rules, users

I installed the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module to grant access of the individual fields to the roles.

I need to change the permission of some fields when an event occurs. How do I can add the field edit permission to the *Action* component of the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no way you can "*add the field edit permission to the Action component of the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module*" (as in your question), which is somehow confirmed in the [Post installation Support forum](https://www.drupal.org/forum/22) via the issue about "[Field Edit Permissions Based on Rule?](https://www.drupal.org/node/1230542)" also.

However, in [one of the comments](https://www.drupal.org/node/1230542#comment-4795514) of that link, there is an interesting work around that might work in your case also:

> Create a user role that has editing permissions for the field, then assign that user role to a user with Rules when the conditions you require are met.
>
> You'd then possibly need to remove that role after updating the content depending on your workflow.

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7.